# noscriptタグが、サーバ環境でのみ、bodyの中に入ってしまう現象

Tags: php, apache, dom

私のPHPプロジェクトで以下のようなテンプレートがあります。（bodyの中身やheadの中身はわかりやすいように取り除いています。）

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <noscript></noscript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

以上のテンプレートファイルを以下のPHPスクリプトで読み込んで表示させています。

```
    $file = file_get_contents( $templatePath ); 
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true; // not working
    $dom->encoding = 'UTF-8'; 

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8') , LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING );
    libxml_clear_errors();

    echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

このコードは、自分のmacのXAMMP上ではそのまま表示され、問題ありません。

しかし、サーバにこのコードを上げてブラウザで見ると、以下のように表示され、
noscriptタグがBodyの中に入ってしまいます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <noscript></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

どなたかこの現象がなぜ起こるか分かりますでしょうか。
開発環境は以下です。
環境に差がありますが、noscript以外は問題なく動いているので、
関係なさそうに思いますが。。

【環境】
Local
- XAMPP on my Mac
- Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.6.20

Server
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.6.15

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 英語は本家に投稿すべきです。If you want to question in English. here -> http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: 失礼しました。日本語で書きました。

Comment: XAMMP上とサーバ+ブラウザ上、それぞれどのようにしてHTMLコードを確認しましたか?

Comment: ブラウザ上のデベロッパーツールで確認しました。
curl -X get [URL]でも同様でした。

Comment: `noscript`タグはＨＴＭＬ４では`head`タグ内に書けない。ＸＨＴＭＬ（ＸＭＬ）では無効なのでそこらへんが関係有るのかも。

Comment: HTML5です。
問題は
ローカルではうまく表示され、
サーバではnoscriptがbodyに入ってしまうという点です。

Comment: HTML5でも head内ではlink要素、style要素、meta要素しか書けないことはOK?

Comment: `HTML4.01ではnoscript要素をhead要素内に配置することは仕様として認められていませんでしたが、 HTML5ではhead要素内に配置してもよいことになっています。`とのこと。
出典：http://www.htmq.com/html5/noscript.shtml

Comment: 一つ前のコメントではHTML5の場合NOSCRIPTタグの内容に制限があることを言ってます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決しました。   
原因は**libxml**でした。   
ローカルの**libxml**のバージョンが**2.8.0**     
サーバの**libxml**のバージョンが**2.7.6**でした。

そしてこの[changelog](http://xmlsoft.org/news.html)によると、
2.8.0のバージョンにて
`HTML parser error with <noscript> in the <head>`
head内のnoscriptのパーサーエラーが直されたとのこと。
なので**2.8.0にバージョンを上げる事で解決しました**。
まさかCのライブラリのバグだったとは、、、たどり着くのにかなり時間を要しました。。。